# if W, X independent given Y then W,X independent given Y,Z

Tags: conditional-probability, independence

Let $W,X,Y,Z$ be random variables and suppose $W\perp\!\!\perp X\mid Y$. Would adding another variable in the conditioning set alter the independence? Is $W\perp\!\!\perp X\mid Y,Z$ ?

I think in general it is not true because it doesn't seem to be easily provable just using Bayes...

Comment: it's not true. Also, writing $X\mid Y$ as a random variable is a bit strange, because in general it's not.

Comment: @Surb by $W\perp\!\!\perp X\mid Y$ I mean W and X are independent given Y. Meaning P(W|Y)=P(W|Y,X)

Comment: I know, but $X\mid Y$ is in general not a random variable, so writting $W\perp\!\!\perp X\mid Y$ is not a good thing.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand where the problem is